# separation of model and controller in mvc pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

declaring entity framework command or dataset(ado.net) for access  or manipulating data in mvc  pattern should be in model as i know , when i want to get list of my object in database all method should be in model and return list , controller just should get that and pass it to view ,

but as i see in many code decalaring method in controller is used , like [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320285/buddy-viewmodel-with-linq-join)

```
 //I get logged in user properties
        var user = db.UserProperties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);            
        Buddyship allBudees = db1.Buddyships.SingleOrDefault(u =>u.BuddiedByUserId == user.UserId);
        var buds = from u in db.UserProperties
                   join m in db1.Buddyships on u.UserId equals m.BuddiedByUserId
                   where m.BuddiedByUserId == user.UserId
                   select new { u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.SchoolName, u.UserId };

        var buddyviewmodel = new BuddyViewModel(buds //don't know what to put here);

        return View(buddyviewmodel);
```

this part of code should be in model or controller ?

Comment: What would be the point of having a controller, that doesn't control anything? An action method that does nothing more but call some other method, and pass the result of that other method to a view, seems like a waiste of space and time to me.

Comment: if one method needs to call more than one time , and declare it in controller , what happend , in each controller i should declare that !

Comment: Sure, controllers obviously can call other methods, amonst other reasons for code reuse. But a method that does exactly what one specific action method should do, except passing its result to a view, will not be reusable (unless you have two action methods that do exactly the same thing - which would be very bad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally this code belongs in the business layer. I usually create a service layer between my data layer (which uses EF) and the controller. The service (`UserService` for example) returns a domain model to the controller. The controller then maps this to a ViewModel and returns the view. This way you abstract data access away from the controller so you won't have (the same) LINQ queries all over the place.

In your case the controller will look like:

```
Buddyship buddies = _buddyService.GetBuddiesByUserId(user.UserId);
BuddyViewModel buddyViewModel = new BuddyViewModel(buddies);
return View(buddyViewModel);
```

For really small projects, this code is just fine in the controller, but definitely not in your domain model classes.

Comment: so can u give some example which data should be defined in model ?

Comment: @Moslem7026 the Model, as in Model-View-Controller, itself is a layer in your application and usually divided in sub layers, as I propose, like data-access, business logic (services) and also your domain entities. We usually call those domain entities 'models' as well. These entities are mapped to tables in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This amount of code is fine in your controller action. The model in MVC is responsible for business logic around the data, but the actual retrieval of that data is in fact the job of the controller. Since things like where-clauses and selection of only certain columns would be specific to the needs of each view, it wouldn't even really make sense to stash this in the model. The model should ideally be able to serve *any* view (though things like view models should be employed around the model to encapsulate the needs of the specific view in play).

Answer (score 0):

In the controller is fine. If and when that code needs to be reused then move it to a service class.